# Perl read data from file and extract certain line content

Tags: perl, fetch

I am extracting certain data from file. Script should fetch `Element` value from given data based on `active` status.
If the status is active I need to get corresponding Element value from previous line.

My code is below and its working perfeclty fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @list;
my @lines = <DATA>;
foreach (0 .. $#lines) {
    chomp $lines[$_];
    next if (/^\s+$/);
    if ($lines[$_+1] =~ /active : yes/){
        if($lines[$_] =~ /Element=(\w+)/){
            push (@list, $1);
        }
    }
}
print Dumper(\@list);

__DATA__
Data : Element=123456
active : yes

Data : Element=789101
active : yes

Data : Element=23456
active : no
```

Expected dumper output is:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '123456',
          '789101'
        ];
```

1. I need experts suggestion is this right way to fetch the data?
2. The `Empty` lines which sepates each data contents not skiping using `next if (/^\s+$/);` statement.

Comment: This queries one past the array boundary with `$lines[$_+1]` in the last round of iteration when `$_` is `$#lines` -- the last index in array.  That should draw a warning.  Do you not get a warning?  /// What you posted tests with regex against index in `next if...`, not an element, but I understand that that's a typo (then edit the post to correct it?)

Comment: Otherwise, you don't need nested `if` -- just `(if ... and ...)`

Comment: @zdim Yes I'm getting a warning.

Comment: Ah, OK; that information belongs to the question, that's important. So you need to be careful with those indices (always the case when you're down to indices!) ... but it looks like you need not go to the last one, since it gets checked when the loop is at the one before.  Then just `for my $i (0..$#lines-1)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the structure of the code, you can simplify it by matching both the `Element` line and the `active` line at the same time in a regular expression.

```
my @list;

# read all the input data into $data
local $/;
my $data = <DATA> ;

while  ($data =~ /Element=(\d+)\nactive : yes/g)
{
    push @list, $1
}

print Dumper(\@list);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no right or wrong here, but this is what I'd do.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @list;
$/ = '';

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  next unless /active : yes/;
  if (/Element=(\d+)/) {
    push (@list, $1);
  }
}
print Dumper(\@list);

__DATA__
Data : Element=123456
active : yes

Data : Element=789101
active : yes

Data : Element=23456
active : no
```

The biggest difference is to use `$/ = ''` to put Perl into "paragraph mode", meaning that each time round the loop, you're dealing with an entire record (i.e. both lines together). This makes some of the logic somewhat easier.

Comment: Very helpful suggestion @Dave.

Answer (score 0):

> The Empty lines which sepates each data contents not skiping using
>   next if (/^\s+$/); statement.

The regular expression `/^\s+$/` will only match blank lines that have at least one white space character.

You need `/^\s*$/`. That will match blank lines that have zero or more white space characters.

Comment: I did a mistake. It should be ```next if ($lines[$_] =~ /^\s+$/);```.